# Is there any subspace clustering method for dealing with numerical attributes?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis, unsupervised-learning

I am trying to apply some clustering method on my datasets (with numerical dimensions). But I'm convinced that the features have different weights for different clusters. I read that there is an approach called soft subspace clustering that tries do identify the clusters and the weights of the features for each cluster simultaneously. However, the algorithms that I have found apre applied only to categorical data.

I am trying to identify some algorithm of soft subspace clustering for numerical. Do you know if there is any, or how can I adapt methods originally designed to deal with categorical data for dealing with numerical data (I think that it would necessary to propose some way of measuring the relevance of each numerical feature in each cluster)?

Comment: SUBCLU, DBSCAN, SUBSCALE?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are dozens of subspace clustering algorithms.

You'll need to do a proper literature research, this is too broad to cover in a QA like stack overflow. Look for (surprise) "subspace clustering", but also include "biclustering", for example.

Comment: But biclustering is a kind of HARD subspace clustering. I'm looking for SOFT subspace clustering, for numerical data.

Comment: Out of these dozen, I am pretty sure some are soft, or can be trivially turned into a soft clustering. And almost *all* them will be numerical data.